# Custom Message upon clicking action button in r

Tags: shiny, rstudio

How can I get a custom message (the message includes a mini table depending on reactive values) once the action button is clicked in shiny?. Here is my code. The message should include the reactive table where I call it as rows().

```
 library(shiny)
 library(datasets)
 library(rhandsontable)
 library(data.table)


 my_message= writeLines("validation is not successful. \nCheck following 
 commodities:\nCPCCode  Commodity  Year")

 # This is the message I want when action button is clicked


 # validation is not successful. Please check the following commodities:

 #CPCCode    Commodity     Year
 # 100           Maize      2010
 # 200           Rice       2015
 # 300           Tea       2016
 # 400           Banana      2014
 #.
 #.
 #.
 # and so on. The table can be upto max 50 rows

 ui = fluidPage(

 actionButton("message", "message")
 )

 server = function(input,output,session){

 rows= reactive({


d=data.frame(CPCCode=100, Commodity="Maize", Year= 2010)
d$Commodity = as.character(d$Commodity)
d=rbind(d, c(200, "Rice", "2015"))
d=rbind(d, c(300,"Tea", 2016))

})


observeEvent(input$message,{
if (is.null(input$message) || input$message == 0){return()}

 isolate({
  input$message  
    the_message <- paste("validation is not successful")
    js_string <- 'alert("SOMETHING");'
    js_string <- sub("SOMETHING",the_message,js_string)
    session$sendCustomMessage(type='jsCode', list(value = js_string))  
    })

   })

}

 shinyApp(ui,server)
```

## EDITED. It shows only the first row of the table. Any suggestions would be appreciated

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
library(rhandsontable)
library(data.table)


my_message= writeLines("validation is not successful. \nCheck following 
commodities:\nCPCCode  Commodity  Year")

# This is the message I want when action button is clicked


# validation is not successful. Please check the following commodities:

#CPCCode    Commodity     Year
# 100           Maize      2010
# 200           Rice       2015
# 300           Tea       2016
# 400           Banana      2014
#.
#.
#.
# and so on. The table can be upto max 50 rows



 ui = fluidPage(

  actionButton("show", "Show modal dialog")

  )

 server = function(input, output) {


 rows= reactive({


  d=data.frame(CPCCode=100, Commodity="Maize", Year= 2010)
  d$Commodity = as.character(d$Commodity)
  d=rbind(d, c(200, "Rice", "2015"))
  d=rbind(d, c(300,"Tea", 2016))

  })



 # Return the UI for a modal dialog with data selection input. If 'failed' 
 is
 # TRUE, then display a message that the previous value was invalid.
 dataModal <- function(failed = FALSE) {
 modalDialog(

  span("Validation is not successful", rows()),


  footer = tagList(

    actionButton("ok", "OK")
    )
   )
  }


 observeEvent(input$show, {
   showModal(dataModal())
   })


  observeEvent(input$ok, {

  removeModal()

  })


   }



      shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: You can use `modal Dialog`. Refer to [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/modalDialog.html) link.

Comment: But bit confused how to associate my situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display table in the `modalDialog` you will need to add a `dataTableOutput` inside the `modalDialog` and render the table after the `modalDialog` is created. I have edited your server code to do the same. Hopefully this helps you.

```
server = function(input, output) {

    rows= reactive({
      d=data.frame(CPCCode=100, Commodity="Maize", Year= 2010)
      d$Commodity = as.character(d$Commodity)
      d=rbind(d, c(200, "Rice", "2015"))
      d=rbind(d, c(300,"Tea", 2016))

    })

    # Return the UI for a modal dialog with data selection input. If 'failed' 
    # is
    # TRUE, then display a message that the previous value was invalid.
    dataModal <- function(failed = FALSE) {
      modalDialog(

        span("Validation is not successful"),

        dataTableOutput("table"),

        footer = tagList(

          actionButton("ok", "OK")
        )
      )
    }


    observeEvent(input$show, {
      showModal(dataModal())
      output$table <- renderDataTable({rows()})
    })


    observeEvent(input$ok, {
      removeModal()
    })

  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! Very useful!

Comment: Could you accept it if your question has been answered?